# How to use GETDATE without affecting the whole column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, default-value

I want to use default function:

```
[Date] date default GETDATE ()
```

I have a large table and I only want this code to start from now on, and from the beginning of the table.

For example, if I have a table with 4000 rows and then I use the code above, it will give the same date to all the 4000 rows, and this is exactly what I want to avoid.

Comment: What date should the first row have? the second row? which columns defines the order of the rows?

Answer (score 8):

Do not worry. The column is going to have `NULL` value for old rows, if `WITH VALUES` option is not specified. As per [official documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187742.aspx):

> WITH VALUES
>
> Specifies that the value given in DEFAULT constant_expression is
>   stored in a new column added to existing rows. If the added column
>   allows null values and WITH VALUES is specified, the default value is
>   stored in the new column, added to existing rows. If WITH VALUES is
>   not specified for columns that allow nulls, the value NULL is stored
>   in the new column in existing rows. If the new column does not allow
>   nulls, the default value is stored in new rows regardless of whether
>   WITH VALUES is specified.

So, when you add your new column, `NULL` values will be added for all existing rows.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StackOverflowTB]
(
    [ID] TINYINT
);
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[StackOverflowTB] ([ID])
VALUES (1), (2), (3);
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StackOverflowTB]
ADD [Date] DATE DEFAULT(GETDATE())
GO

SELECT *
FROM [StackOverflowTB]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[StackOverflowTB] ([ID])
VALUES (4);
GO

SELECT *
FROM [StackOverflowTB]
GO

DROP TABLE [dbo].[StackOverflowTB]
GO
```

As you can see from the screenshot below, the `default` value is "working" for new rows only:

[image]

Comment: Hello again, the column that i have does have dates. they are formatted in datetime. but now i want the column date to register automatically without deleting the previous data.
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: @Kalash The same thing apply. Adding default value to the column is not going to delete the old data if you do not specify the `WITH VALUES` option.